Getting delay in the video stream while streaming to webrtc
I am working with Gstreamer 1.16.3 application on the Ubuntu 20.4. The application is in such a way that, I have USB camera which is giving output a H264 encoded data, and using the laptop microphone for the audio. The video and audio should be streaming to the connected peer via Webrtcbin, and that is working for now. To extend this functionality, in my application, I am saving the encoded video and audio in a local file in .mp4 format. So, when streaming is not happenning, local save of the devices data is being done. So, here is my gstreamer pipeline,
    gchar *gst_pipeline = g_strdup_printf(

    // Vieo source input selector
    "input-selector name=videoinputsel sync-mode=1 sync-streams=true "

    // Video sink output selector
    "output-selector name=videooutputsel pad-negotiation-mode=1 resend-latest=true "

    // Audio source input selector
    "input-selector name=audioinputsel sync-mode=1 sync-streams=true "

    // Audio sink output selector
    "output-selector name=audiooutputsel pad-negotiation-mode=1 resend-latest=true "
    
    // File source used to streaming
    "multifilesrc name=multifilesrc location=./test-video.mp4 ! qtdemux name=multifiledemuxer "
 
    // Video source (v4l2src)
    "v4l2src device=/dev/video2 do-timestamp=true ! video/x-h264, format=h264, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1, "
    "profile=baseline, stream-format=byte-stream ! h264parse name=h264parser config-interval=-1 ! videoinputsel.sink_0 "
           
    // Local file video source
    // Dynamically adding the video src pad of qtdemuxer to video input selector sink_1

    // Video input selector with video output selector
    "videoinputsel.src ! videooutputsel.sink "
  
    // WebRTC video path  
    "videooutputsel.src_0 ! rtph264pay config-interval=-1 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, encoding-name=H264, "
    "payload=96 ! webrtcbin name=webrtcbin async=false sync=true "

    // Local file video path
    "videooutputsel.src_1 ! splitmuxsink name=filesplitmuxer async=false max-size-time=10000000000 muxer=mp4mux sync=true "

    // Audio source
    "alsasrc name=sounddev device=\"hw:0,7\" do-timestamp=true ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, channels=2, "
    "rate=16000 ! opusenc ! audioinputsel.sink_0 "
 
    // Local file audio source
    // Dynamically adding the audio src pad of qtdemuxer to audio input selector sink_1

    // Audio input selector with audio output selector
    "audioinputsel.src ! audiooutputsel.sink "
  
    // WebRTC audio path  
    "audiooutputsel.src_0 ! rtpopuspay ! application/x-rtp, media=audio, encoding-name=OPUS, payload=97 ! webrtcbin. "

    // Local file audio path
    "audiooutputsel.src_1 ! filesplitmuxer.audio_0 "
);


so, in this pipeline, as you can see that, I am using input-selectors and output-selectors for the audio and video paths. So, input-selector is used to select between streaming live video and audio source or the streaming of local file to the webrtc. The pad linking of the qtdemux is done with input selectors in the callback. Now, in first, the application is running, then the streaming is done via webrtcbin of the video and audio, and everything is in sync. When a timer function is called after 20 seconds, I am just changing the active pads of the output-selectors of the audio and video path, and then the video and audio is save in the local file, and is also good, I can see the mp4 files, with everything in the sync. When, next time, the change in active-pad is done in the timer function, and streaming is started with live audio and video, the video is lagged somewhat near to 1s, but the audio is in real-time, which is a issue for me now, which I need to solve. Though, after switching again to local file sink, the file is saving correctly, and everything is in sync, but with webrtc streaming, the lag is always there with video. Can you guys please help me with this?
I tried different properties of the opusencoder, webrtc, and tried inserting queues between the input sources and sinks, but nothing worked well till now, I am sharing my switching active pad code also,
typegboolean SwitchOperationForSink(gpointer user_data)
{
    guint64 latency_time, buffer_time;
    GstFlowReturn ret;
    SharedData *VarUserData = static_cast<SharedData*>(user_data);

    if(STREAM_CAMERA_TO_WEBRTC == VarUserData->StreamStatus.load())
    {
        // if(GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE == gst_element_set_state(globalCtx->gstpipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED))
        // {
        //     g_printerr("Failed to set pipeline to PAUSED\n\r");
        //     return TRUE;
        // } else { /* Do nothing */ }

        VarUserData->StreamStatus.store(STREAM_CAMERA_TO_BUFFER_DATA);

        g_object_get(G_OBJECT(globalCtx->sounddev), "latency-time", &latency_time, NULL);
        g_object_get(G_OBJECT(globalCtx->sounddev), "buffer-time", &buffer_time, NULL);
        g_print("Sound outputs before -> L:%ld, B:%ld\n\r", latency_time, buffer_time);
        
        // while(!SwitchingOk.load()) {;}
        // while(!SwitchingOk) {;}

        g_object_set(globalCtx->video_output_sel, "active-pad", globalCtx->video_output_sel_pad_src1, NULL);
        g_object_set(globalCtx->audio_output_sel, "active-pad", globalCtx->audio_output_sel_pad_src1, NULL);

        
        g_object_get(G_OBJECT(globalCtx->sounddev), "latency-time", &latency_time, NULL);
        g_object_get(G_OBJECT(globalCtx->sounddev), "buffer-time", &buffer_time, NULL);
        g_print("Sound outputs after -> L:%ld, B:%ld\n\r", latency_time, buffer_time);

        // if(GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE == gst_element_set_state(globalCtx->gstpipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING))
        // {
        //     g_printerr("Failed to set pipeline to PLAYING\n\r");
        //     return TRUE;
        // } else { /* Do nothing */ }

        g_print("Stream live source to filesink.\n\r");
    } else {

        // if(GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE == gst_element_set_state(globalCtx->gstpipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED))
        // {
        //     g_printerr("Failed to set pipeline to PAUSED\n\r");
        //     return TRUE;
        // } else { /* Do nothing */ }

        VarUserData->StreamStatus.store(STREAM_CAMERA_TO_WEBRTC);

        g_object_get(G_OBJECT(globalCtx->sounddev), "latency-time", &latency_time, NULL);
        g_object_get(G_OBJECT(globalCtx->sounddev), "buffer-time", &buffer_time, NULL);
        g_print("Sound outputs before -> L:%ld, B:%ld\n\r", latency_time, buffer_time);

        // while(!SwitchingOk.load()) {;}
        // while(!SwitchingOk) {;}

        g_object_set(globalCtx->video_output_sel, "active-pad", globalCtx->video_output_sel_pad_src0, NULL);
        g_object_set(globalCtx->audio_output_sel, "active-pad", globalCtx->audio_output_sel_pad_src0, NULL);

        g_object_get(G_OBJECT(globalCtx->sounddev), "latency-time", &latency_time, NULL);
        g_object_get(G_OBJECT(globalCtx->sounddev), "buffer-time", &buffer_time, NULL);
        g_print("Sound outputs after -> L:%ld, B:%ld\n\r", latency_time, buffer_time);

        // if(GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE == gst_element_set_state(globalCtx->gstpipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING))
        // {
        //     g_printerr("Failed to set pipeline to PLAYING\n\r");
        //     return TRUE;
        // } else { /* Do nothing */ }

        g_print("Stream live source to webrtc\n\r");
    }

    return TRUE;
}

I tried the properties of different elements which are present in the pipeline. Tried with inserting queue in the pipeline, but nothing worked till yet.
